# Connect LINQ to SQL to a database project as opposed to a physical database?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2019

I want to make some changes to my database and it would be nice if I could update LINQ to SQL based on my data model as specified in a dbproj or sqlproj file rather than having to deploy my changes to an actual database and import them back in every time I want to change something. Is there any way to do this?

edit: to clarify, what I want to do is take a DACPAC project that I've created and generate/update a DBML file from it. I want to do this so that I don't have to go deploy all my experimental database changes every time I want to change my code, rather I can deploy them all at once when I'm ready to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I want to do is take a DACPAC project that I've created and generate/update a DBML file from it.

There is no built-in tooling for that in LINQ 2 SQL or in Entity Framework.

Comment: No built-in tooling? Is there a third party plugin?

Comment: Not that I know of.  L2S is not widely used any more, and in any case you always have a database around at design-time.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a workaround: if I publish the DACPAC project to localhost, I can connect to it in the DBML so I can set things up without actually deploying changes to a development server.